# Hide link icon on razor view based on value of ViewModel .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to show or hide a link icon based on value of a Viewmodel

here is what I have try so far but it doesn't work

```
 @foreach (var t in Model.Tickets)
   {
    if (t.ConditionID == 2)
       {
        <a asp-controller="Replies" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="@item.TicketID"><i 
        class="fas fa-reply"></i>|</a>

    }
 }
```

Any idea? thank you

Comment: In my opinion, your code is completely correct, I would like to ask you where the problem occurred.

Comment: it always displays the icon in all cases...

Comment: You can try to simulate a few pieces of data, it works very well here, or you can post more details about your problem.

Comment: You can see my test here https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYqye.gif

Comment: thank you...I also try `Model.Tickets.ToList()` but it doesn;t work....

Comment: Can you share all your View?

Comment: I made it to work as `Model.Tickets.Where(t=>t.TicketID == item.TicketID)`...thank you very much

Comment: I think you can also do this,change`asp-route-id="@item.TicketID"` to `asp-route-id="@t.TicketID`